# iOS app rejected by Apple due to IPV6 issue but crash report indicates assertion failed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

My iOS app does not use any networking and works fine on my iPhone, but Apple rejected it supposedly due to IPv6 incompatibility issues.

```
2. 1 PERFORMANCE: APP COMPLETENESS
Performance - 2.1


Your app crashes on iPhone running iOS 10.0.3 connected to an IPv6 network when we:

Specifically, we found your app crashes when we tap “Analyze.”

We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.
```

However when I symbolicated the crash report they sent, it shows a particular thread crashed. The backtrace is below.

```
    Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.HealthKit.HKHealthStore.client.0x1700f6d00
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100273ae8 _assertionFailed(StaticString, String, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never (__hidden#14874_:167)
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100273ae8 _assertionFailed(StaticString, String, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never (__hidden#14874_:167)
2   PickerTest                      0x00000001000c1d1c type metadata accessor for String? (PyschicBrain.swift:0)
3   PickerTest                      0x00000001000bfe78 PsychicBrain.(isHeartRateInfoAvailableForDates() -> Bool).(closure #1) (PyschicBrain.swift:0)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f98d200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f98d1c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f99b444 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f9909a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f99b940 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 360
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f99d38c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f99d0ec _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fb952c8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018fb94db4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Stack frame #3 (above) says the closure in the function isHeartRateInfoAvailableForDates() failed, which means the HKSampleQuery failed.

My question: I'm assuming this is because no heart-rate data was found for that interval. On my phone, in this scenario, samples.count() returns 0 and hence the function returns FALSE. When Apple folks test it, obviously they get a different error. I've asked Apple for console logs but I would like to know a more elegant way of error handling.

```
func isHeartRateInfoAvailableForDates() -> Bool {
    predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: pvtStartDate, end: pvtEndDate, options: HKQueryOptions())
    guard let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate) else {
        fatalError("HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier failed")
    }

let dispatchGrp = DispatchGroup()

// Entering query block
//
dispatchGrp.enter()

let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: predicate, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit), sortDescriptors: nil) {
    query, results, error in

    guard let samples = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
        fatalError("An error occured fetching the user's heart rate: \(error?.localizedDescription)");
    }
    self.pvtSampleCount = samples.count
    // leave group once query results are available
    dispatchGrp.leave()
    }
pvtHealthStore.execute(query)

// Now wait for the query  to complete
//

dispatchGrp.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)

return pvtSampleCount > 0
```

}

Comment: The `guard` statement is not a closure.  There is only one closure in that function; the closure provided to the `HKSampleQuery` call.  Having `fatalError`/assertions in released code isn't very user friendly. You should display an error alert indicating what went wrong.  Specifically, your code doesn't seem to handle the condition where heart rate data isn't available for the specified dates

Comment: Yes, my bad - I overlooked that. I rephrased the question. I will be removing the fatalError but still wonder why it did not handle the "no data found" error elegantly as it did while testing on my phone. When testing on my phone it does not throw the fatal error. The only explanation is a different error was thrown, hence I've requested Apple for console logs.